# Get attribute from string

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I'm making a database and I have

```
CREATE TABLE reserva ( 
 id_clinica       NUMBER, 
 APOSITIVO       DECIMAL(10,4), 
 ANEGATIVO         DECIMAL(10,4), 
 BPOSITIVO       DECIMAL(10,4), 
 BNEGATIVO         DECIMAL(10,4), 
 ABPOSITIVO       DECIMAL(10,4), 
 ABNEGATIVO         DECIMAL(10,4), 
 OPOSITIVO       DECIMAL(10,4), 
 ONEGATIVO         DECIMAL(10,4), 
);

CREATE TABLE donante (  
 dni_donante     VARCHAR(9), 
 fecha_alta DATE, 
 movil  VARCHAR(9),
 nombre VARCHAR(20),
 apellido1 VARCHAR(20),
 apellido2 VARCHAR(20),
 tipo_sangre VARCHAR(15),
);
```

In the table donante, the attribute "tipo_sangre" will always be "APOSITIVO", "ANEGATIVO", "BPOSITIVO", BNEGATIVO", etc.

I want to make a trigger that when inserting a row on another table, will get the "tipo_sangre" from donante and add a number to it's correspondant attribute of the table reserva.

Is there any way to do that besides declaring a variable for tipo_sangre and doing a switch case?

Thank you beforehand :)

Comment: uhm, rather declare a table with each possible bloodtype and just insert a foreign key value in your reserva table for the correct bloodtype.

Comment: I think `CASE... WHEN...` is the way to go. Theoretically, you can do it with dynamic sql, but it's IMO not worth it.

Comment: First, I don't think this is really a good use of triggers. Second, It appears that your RESERVA table is just keeping a running tally of how many occurrences of something exist in a third table that you haven't described.  If so, it is generally poor design to store data that can and should be computed 'on demand'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the first table is meant to simply give you the count by blood type for the rows in the second table, I would recommend rethinking the database design. You only need a "dimension" table for blood types (a single column, eight rows, showing the names of the blood types). This column should be primary key. Then `tipo-sangre` in `donate` should have a foreign key constraint, referencing this blood types table. Finally, for the count you don't need a table, you need a view. Based on a query like this:

```
select count(case tipo_sangre when 'apositivo' then 1 end) as apositivo,
       count(case tipo_sangre when 'anegativo' then 1 end) as anegativo, 
       .....
       count(case tipo_sangre when 'onegativo' then 1 end) as onegativo
from donate
```

Don't create a separate table to store these counts; that can only cause trouble in the future as you will have redundant data which may, at some point, contradict itself for any number of reasons.

Comment: Thank you, I'm indeed going to redesign the database as itd make more sense to have the type of blood as a separate attribute on the table reserva :)